# Auto-Pairing for Bluetooth PAN clients

Tags: networking, bluetooth

I have setup a Bluetooth Network PAN via Blueman's *Local Services* → *Network* that looks like this:

[image: local services]

However whenever I pair a device to my Ubuntu box so that it can share its network connection, I have to manually confirm the pairing like so:

[image: confirmation dialog 1]

On the Phone I'll see a dialog that states:

```
Bluetooth Pairing Request
"Ubuntu Box" would like to pair with your
iPhone. Confirm that this code is
displayed on "Ubuntu Box".
        127459
```

After which, a set of "accept/deny" notifications pop up on my Ubuntu box which goes one-by-one through the capabilities that should be granted to the iPhone, BNEP being the networking capability, but I'm also asked about Audio sharing:

[image: confirmation dialog 2]

**Question**

I would like to know if it's possible to configure Ubuntu such that when **any** device (not just my iPhone) pairs with my Ubuntu box, it is automatically paired/trusted and that all capabilities are granted to it without my interaction.  This box is in my home, and I want to auto-pair out of convenience for setting up a local network.

Comment: @PRATAP interesting, just out of curiosity if you go to the command line and type: `ifconfig` is that command found? If not, try `apt-get install net-tools`.  FYI I seem to have solved my problem, check my answer below. I'm still doing a bit of testing just to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

The trick was to run my own auth agent, here's what I did:

1. First I disabled the AuthAgent plugin in Blueman (*Bluetooth tray icon -> Plugins -> AuthAgent (**uncheck**)*)

[image: Auth Agent GUI]

2. `sudo apt-get install bluez-tools`
3. `bt-agent --capability=NoInputNoOutput`

After that, I was able to pair and connect without any confirmation on the Ubuntu Box